# Remove button from memory which is removed from Grid

Tags: wpf, memory, button

In my application, i am generating multiple buttons at run time and add it to grid as following

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ListOfMainCategories.Count; i++)
            {
                clsMainCategory tempCat = (clsMainCategory)ListOfMainCategories[i];
                ButtonMainMenuCat btn = CreateMainButton(tempCat.CatTitle, i);
                btn.Margin = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 1); 
                btn.TabIndex = TabIndexNo;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    buttonHomeMenu = btn;
                }
                btn.AddHandler(ButtonMainMenuSubSubCat.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonMainMenuGotFocus), handledEventsToo: false);
                // stackTableViewMainMenu.Children.Add(btn);
                Grid.SetRow(btn, 1);
                Grid.SetColumn(btn, i + 1);
                gridHeader.Children.Add(btn);

            }
```

After on particular event I removed all of these buttons from Grid.

```
gridHeader.Children.RemoveRange(0, gridHeader.Children.Count);
```

Here i Think i also need to Remove or dispose or unload these button from Memory. So How can i do this task ? Please suggest

Comment: That is some horrible code, you should look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), there should be no need to imperatively create and remove buttons.

Comment: you are right. But when i started the project then I was new to WPF and did not get the right way. so I use classic style(as we did in VS2005). However time to time, I change the code for efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo can't dispose of the button in the classical sense as there is nothing to dispose. You are dealing with managed code here. The memory allocation will be cleared up by the garbage collector as long as there are no references. In the code above you are keeping a reference to the button through the routed event handler so call `btn.RemoveHandler` before you remove it from the Grid.

You could take a look at MSDN guidance on the WeakEvent pattern here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850

Comment: tb1.Click -= new RoutedEventHandler(ClickRightSubSubCategoriesItem);
                    tb1.RemoveHandler(ButtonMainMenuSubSubCat.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(ButtonMainMenuSubCatCatNavigationKeys_KeyDown));
                    tb1.RemoveHandler(ButtonMainMenuSubSubCat.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonMainMenuSubSubCatGotFocus));                                         -  whether it is the correct way of remove handler ? Here tb1 is the button

Comment: Your original snippet doesn't show you subscribing to the Click or KeyDown events, but if you are subscribing to them in an analogous way, then yes, your code will correctly remove the handlers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I apply the give snippet for another grid and another type of button.